# Mips Instruction Code

Tags: mips

I am trying to solve a problem of addition of elements in an array in mips. 
[image]

I have to insert nops or rearrange the code so it works but I am not able to. Can someone suggest some Ideas. Thanks

Comment: You need to post your code in the body of your question, not an image of it.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

This is a way using a loop by which you can traverse through the array and calculate the sum of all its element:

```
.data
newline: .asciiz "\n"

array:   .word 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 14, 15, 17, 19

length:  .word 10

sum:     .word 0
    
.text

.globl main

main:

#loop through the array to calculate sum

#array's starting address

la $t0 array 

#loop index, i=0 ($t1=i)

li $t1 0 

#loading the length of array in register t2    

lw $t2 length 

#initialise sum =0 

li $t3 0 

sumLoop:

#get array[i]

lw $t4 ($t0) 

#sum = sum+array[i]

add $t3 $t3 $t4  

#updating countervariable

addi $t1 $t1 1 #i = i+1

add $t0 $t0 4 #update array address

#while i<length , traverse the loop again

#blt (branch less than) (if $t1<$t2 then go through the loop)

blt $t1 $t2 sumLoop

sw $t3 sum  #save sum

#printing the sum on syscall

move $a0 $t3

li $v0 1

syscall

li $v0 10

syscall

.end main
```